# Get columns in mysql based on values of other columns

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to pull some data out of woocommerce and have 90% of what I want working just fine, but the postmeta is killing me.  I'm trying to grab a subset of postmeta entries related to a post rather than all of them, and if I just select one meta_key it works fine, but multiples returns all meta_key/meta_value pairs from the table regardless of post_id.  I am not a dba, I know just enough SQL to get myself in trouble.  Which I've done.  And now I'm looking for some guidance.  Thanks.

```
select meta_key, meta_value from wp_postmeta where post_id=1923
AND meta_key='_billing_first_name'
OR meta_key='_billing_last_name'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `or` criteria is negating `post_id=1923`.  You could use parentheses:

```
select meta_key, meta_value 
from wp_postmeta 
where post_id=1923 and
    (meta_key='_billing_first_name' or meta_key='_billing_last_name')
```

---

But using `in` would probably be your best option:

```
select meta_key, meta_value 
from wp_postmeta 
where post_id=1923 and
    meta_key in ('_billing_first_name', '_billing_last_name')
```

Comment: Ah, fantastic, that did it!  Thank you!